# Error: exception exit with "noproc" snmp_master_agent

Tags: erlang, snmp

I have a problem.
I have this code,

```
    error_logger:tty(true),

    application:start(mnesia), 

    applivation:start(snmp),  

    otp_mib:load(snmp_master_agent),  

    application:start(sasl),  

    application:start(os_mon),  

    os_mon_mib:load(snmp_master_agent),
```

and when I start this code it exits with exception exit:

> ** exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,
>                                          [snmp_master_agent,
>                                           {load_mibs,["/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.6/priv/mibs/OTP-MIB"]},
>                                           infinity]}}

can anyone tell me what it means. what is the reason of this. what process doesn't exists, or how can I solve this problem?

thank you.

Comment: I can say that your call is failing because snmp_master_agent is not started. There should be a registered process by that name. However, I'm not entirely sure how SNMP works in Erlang. A quick glance at the documentation suggests that you're supposed to start the agent prior to calling `otp_mib:load/1`, but I've no idea how to start snmp_master_agent.

Comment: maybe this link could be of use? http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.2/lib/snmp-3.3.8/doc/html/snmp_config.html